# How to assign multiple Objects to one array?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

** I want to store the multiple objects to an array, I have five objects obj1,obj2,obj3,obj4,obj5**

Comment: Hi Salim. Please provide some more context. What have you tried? What is your desired output? Your question is both unclear and too broad.

Comment: All your objects seem to be identical.

Comment: These are the different objects I want to assemble  to one array I am using vue js.

Comment: @barmar these are different objects I want to assemble to one array .

Comment: @salimkhan It's expected that you ask a **specific question**, rather than just asking "How can I do *XYZ*?" without any context, code, etc. A more apt question might explain your desired output, include a snippet of code that you've tried, and ask what's wrong with a specific portion of it.

Comment: `[{...}, {...}, ...]` will create an array of objects.

Comment: If they're different, why are all the property values the same? Just a coincidence?

Comment: I am trying but weak English...

Comment: @salimkhan The problem isn't your English, the problem is that the level of detail you've provided is far too low. Please take a look at the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. It will tell you what you should include in your question to make it easier to understand and make it more likely that you will receive a helpful response.

Comment: msg: [. ] an array while I  assigned the response data to that array the all objects have arrays that I don’t want, but when I map the msg array the objects doesn’t array . I want these objects should assign to one single array. The above code shows every object have array that what I don’t want.

Comment: Ok thanks I am new,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree that this is far too broad and not nearly enough detail. But here are the very basics of adding an object to and array in javascript.

"Add" one object

```
let arr = [];
let obj = {
    "by": "5d7bcc50ca80630017807ada",
    "id": "5d7fd4884680ef00171cf3d4",
    "message": "salaam",
    "to": "5d7f39c6dacf250017ccac85"
};

arr.push(obj);
```

OR

```
let obj = {
    "by": "5d7bcc50ca80630017807ada",
    "id": "5d7fd4884680ef00171cf3d4",
    "message": "salaam",
    "to": "5d7f39c6dacf250017ccac85"
};
let arr = [obj];
```

In your code that was posted it depends on how you are receiving/building these objects but here is a VERY simple example.

```
let obj1 = {
    "by": "5d7bcc50ca80630017807ada",
    "id": "5d7fd4884680ef00171cf3d4",
    "message": "salaam",
    "to": "5d7f39c6dacf250017ccac85",
};
let obj2 = {
    "by": "5d7bcc50ca80630017807ada",
    "id": "5d7fd4884680ef00171cf3d4",
    "message": "salaam",
    "to": "5d7f39c6dacf250017ccac85",
};
let obj3 =  {
    "by": "5d7bcc50ca80630017807ada",
    "id": "5d7fd4884680ef00171cf3d4",
    "message": "salaam",
    "to": "5d7f39c6dacf250017ccac85",
};
let obj4 = {
    "by": "5d7bcc50ca80630017807ada",
    "id": "5d7fd4884680ef00171cf3d4",
    "message": "salaam",
    "to": "5d7f39c6dacf250017ccac85",
};

let arr = [obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4];

OR

let arr = [];
arr.push(obj1);
arr.push(obj2);
arr.push(obj3);
arr.push(obj4);
```

In a VueJS component you could set a key within the data object:

```
data () {
    return {
        arr: []
    }
}
```

In which you would do:

```
this.arr.push(obj);
```

or

```
this.arr = [obj];
```

Both of which are reactive https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Array-Change-Detection

For those that run across this I intentionally left out more complex example or spread operator syntax. My assumption, based on the question, was that they are just getting started and did not want to overwhelm them.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can simply initialize an array by

```
let someArray = [];
```

Then you can add your objects by using spread operator for each one, like this:

```
someArray = [...ObjectReference];
```

Comment: Thanks,let me check it’s working.